# Java CXF: What is the best way to handle Common Objects under different packages or namespaces?

Tags: web-services, java-8, cxf, wsdl2java, apache-commons-beanutils

We're integrating with a 3rd Party webservice by using Wsdl2Java to translate their Schema and endpoints into Java for three different webservices that they offer.

This particular provider uses a lot of the same objects (think objects representing an Address, Money, Weight, etc), but, in their infinite wisdom, they've decided to create a different namespace for each webservice and duplicate the definition of their schemas for each one. The result is you have the following classes output for CXF integration:

> com.thirdpartyguys.api.firstApi.Money
>
> com.thirdpartyguys.api.secondApi.Money
>
> com.thirdpartyguys.api.thirdApi.Money

Translating our data into theirs can involve a lot of business logic and, as a result, we have to define the code that creates the objects in triplicate for each individual Webservice API.

To overcome this problem I created an Interface defined thusly:

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;
public interface CommonObjectInterface<A, R, S> {
    
    A toFirstApi();
    
    R toSecondApi();
    
    S toThirdApi();
    
    default Object doTransform(Object destination, Object source) {
        try {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(destination, source);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Fatal error transforming Object", e);
        }
        return destination;
    }
    
}
```

You would then have each common object implement the interface, define its own constructors, fluent API, etc, and call the toXXX() methods to get the proper form of the object for the respective API.

Right now most of these implementing classes work by keeping a copy of one of the Apis locally, setting data on that, and then transforming it for the proper API using the **doTransform()** method which in its default form uses the **Apache Commons BeanUtils.copyProperties()** method.

It's more elegant than having the same code exist in three different places, but not by much! There's a lot of boilerplate and, even though this won't be getting hammered too much, not that efficient.

I would like to get feedback from the community as to whether this is a good idea or if there are better approaches. A similar question [was asked years ago here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567409/create-a-common-converter-for-objects-from-different-packages), but I don't know if better solutions have emerged since it was asked. I imagine the best thing would be configuring wsdl2Java to allow setting the namespace at runtime, but from my initial research this does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is specific to this exact situation:

1) A webservice provider that has the same object in different namespaces
2) Using wsdl2Java or some underlying Apache CXF technology to generate the web artifacts for writing a client.

This is a fringe case so I'm not sure how helpful this will be to the community but the trick is to account for a few situations where a copyProperties method doesn't work. In this case I'm using Spring's BeanUtils and BeanWrapper classes although I'm sure this could be adapted for Apache as well. The following code does the trick:

```
final String TARGET_PACKAGE = "com.thirdpartyguys.api";
public Object doTransform(Object destination, Object source) {
    /*
     * This will copy all properties for the same data type for which there is a getter method in
     * source, and a setter method in destination
     */
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, destination);

    BeanWrapper sourceWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
    for(PropertyDescriptor p : sourceWrapper.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        /*
         * Properties that are references to other schema objects are identical in structure, but have
         * different packages. We need to copy these separately
         */
        if(p.getPropertyType().getPackage().getName().startsWith(TARGET_PACKAGE)) {
            try {
                commonPropertyCopy(destination, source, p);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Fatal error creating Data", e);
            }
        }
        /*
         * Properties that reference list don't create setters according to the Apache CXF
         * convention. We have to call the get method and addAll()
         */
        else if(Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(p.getPropertyType())) {
            try {
                collectionCopy(destination, source, p);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Fatal error creating Data", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return destination;
}

private void collectionCopy(Object destination, Object source, PropertyDescriptor sourceProperty) throws Exception {
    BeanWrapper destWrapper= new BeanWrapperImpl(destination);
    PropertyDescriptor destProperty = destWrapper.getPropertyDescriptor(sourceProperty.getName());
    Collection<?> sourceCollection = (Collection<?>) sourceProperty.getReadMethod().invoke(source);
    Collection<Object> destCollection = (Collection<Object>) destProperty.getReadMethod().invoke(destination);
    destCollection.addAll(sourceCollection);

}

private void commonPropertyCopy(Object destination, Object source, PropertyDescriptor sourceProperty) throws Exception {
    if(sourceProperty.getPropertyType().isEnum()) {
        instantiateEnum(destination, source, sourceProperty);
    }
    else {
        instantiateObject(destination, source, sourceProperty);
    }
}

private void instantiateEnum(Object destination, Object source, PropertyDescriptor sourceProperty) throws Exception {
    BeanWrapper destWrapper= new BeanWrapperImpl(destination);
    Enum<?> sourceEnum = (Enum<?>) sourceProperty.getReadMethod().invoke(source);
    PropertyDescriptor destProperty = destWrapper.getPropertyDescriptor(sourceProperty.getName());

    Object enumValue = Enum.valueOf(destProperty.getPropertyType().asSubclass(Enum.class), sourceEnum.name());
    destProperty.getWriteMethod().invoke(destination, enumValue);
}

private void instantiateObject(Object destination, Object source, PropertyDescriptor sourceProperty) throws Exception {
    Object subObj = sourceProperty.getReadMethod().invoke(source);
    if(subObj!=null) {
        BeanWrapper destWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(destination);
        String subObjName = sourceProperty.getName();
        PropertyDescriptor destProperty = destWrapper.getPropertyDescriptor(subObjName);
        Class<?> propertyType = destProperty.getReadMethod().getReturnType();
        Object subObjCopy = propertyType.getConstructor().newInstance();
        doTransform(subObjCopy, subObj);
        destProperty.getWriteMethod().invoke(destination, subObjCopy);
    }
}
```

instantiateObject is used to create new instances of the "identical" objects from different packages. This also applies for Enumerated types and requires its own method, hence the implementation of instantiateEnum. Finally, the default CXF implemenation offers no setter method for Lists. We handle this situation in collectionCopy.